# Merge list-items if separated by "/" python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an existing list containing information on your drive-direction. The heading is sometimes separated by "/" 's. I'd like to merge the list-items only which are separated by such a slash. In the example this would merge indices: 5, 7, 9 and 11 and deleting 6, 8 and 10.

```
original_list = ['Keep', 'right', 'to continue on', 'Exit 18', ', follow signs for', 'Hoograven', '/', 'Lunetten', '/', 'Houten', '/', 'Nieuwegein', '']
output_list = ['Keep', 'right', 'to continue on', 'Exit 18', ', follow signs for', 'Hoograven/Lunetten/Houten/Nieuwegein', '']
```

I cannot find a nice solution which can handle different amount of slashes in the list. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This joins the strings together and then uses replace to remove the separators around the slashes and then splits it up again:

```
'@'.join(L).replace('@/@', '/').split('@')
```

Is used like this:

```
>>> '@'.join(['Keep', 'right', 'to continue on', 'Exit 18', ', follow signs for', 'Hoograven', '/', 'Lunetten', '/', 'Houten', '/', 'Nieuwegein', '']).replace('@/@', '/').split('@')
['Keep', 'right', 'to continue on', 'Exit 18', ', follow signs for', 'Hoograven/Lunetten/Houten/Nieuwegein', '']
```

This works as long as the separator chosen does not appear in the strings.

Comment: That is very clever, thanks! And it's even better than you say; If the seperator appears in the string, this wouldnt cause any damage to it, because it's simply merged again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Not really elegant solution, but it should work. It gives different results than the previous answer in some cases (e.g., slashes as first and last element in `original_list`), which may be good for you:

```
original_list = ['/', '/', 'Keep', 'right', 'to continue on', 'Exit 18', ', follow signs for', 'Hoograven', '/', '/', '/', 'Lunetten', '/', 'Houten', '/', 'Nieuwegein', '', '/', '/']
new_list = []

for i in range(len(original_list)):
    if len(new_list) > 0 and i > 0 and (original_list[i] == '/' or original_list[i-1] == '/'):
        new_list[-1] += original_list[i]
    else:
        new_list.append(original_list[i])

print new_list
```

Result:

```
['//Keep', 'right', 'to continue on', 'Exit 18', ', follow signs for', 'Hoograven///Lunetten/Houten/Nieuwegein', '//']
```